# Extracting and Loading image from XML tag

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

I'm using XmlPullParser to parse xml file , i successfully loaded all the other tags but i want to know how to extract the image from this tag and the line of description as shown below

Image

```
img border='0' 
 src='https://www.eyefootball.com/imghold/thumbChristianEriksen_2019.jpg'>
```

this line too

```
<BR>Christian Eriksen has reportedly made the decision to leave Tottenham 
 Hotspur in the New Year after declining to sign a new contract.</p>
```

this is the whole tag which contains them both

```
 <description><![CDATA[<p><A 
 HREF='https://www.eyefootball.com/news/42653/Christian-Eriksen-Tottenham- 
 Hotspur-transfer-decision.html'><img border='0' 
 src='https://www.eyefootball.com/imghold/thumbChristianEriksen_2019.jpg'></A> 
 <BR>Christian Eriksen has reportedly made the decision to leave Tottenham 
 Hotspur in the New Year after declining to sign a new contract.</p>]]> </description>
```

This is how i'm getting the data from xml

```
     try {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.eyefootball.com/football_news.xml");

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();

            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);

            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            xpp.setInput(GetInputStream(url), "utf-8");

            boolean insideItem = false;

            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                    if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                        insideItem = true;
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        if (insideItem) {
                            rssModel.setTitle(xpp.nextText());
                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")) {
                        if (insideItem) {
                            rssModel.setPublished(xpp.nextText());
                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("guid")) {
                        if (insideItem) {
                            rssModel.setLinks(xpp.nextText());
                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                     /// i want to get the child tags ( img and last line ) from  
                     /// descritpion tag
                    }

                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

                    insideItem = false;

                    list.add(rssModel);

                }
                eventType = xpp.next();

            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            exception = e;
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            exception = e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            exception = e;
        }

    }
```

Thank you

Comment: You can load images from url or from files using picasso.
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41157030/5705721).

Comment: but if you dont mind , i want to mainly know how to get it from the tag , cause i used getAttributeValue(null,"img"); it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
First extract your tag like done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4076993/5705721)

and then you can load images from url or from files using picasso. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41157030/5705721)

Check this link for dealing with child node
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11588872/5705721

Comment: Thank you for suggesting me this way , but in my case i'm using XmlPullParser , is there any example of getting a tag attribute value using XmlPullParser thank you.

Comment: Since there is child tag inside the root tag , should i call again ( xpp.getName().equals("childtag") and then assign the value to my view